# oracle procedure with clob as in parameter (large text)

Tags: java, oracle, spring, stored-procedures, ibatis

I'm facing a problem when trying to insert a large text object into oracle database using procedure.

My program has to insert thousands of items into oracle database, as the performance issue of inserting one-by-one, I wrote a oracle procedure and insert all item at once.

Ibatis:

```
<parameterMap id="EttAttrCall" class="java.util.Map">
        <parameter property="ettAttrLst" jdbcType="CLOB" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="pjtId" jdbcType="VARCHAR2" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
        <parameter property="createUser" jdbcType="VARCHAR2" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="IN"/>
    </parameterMap>
    <procedure id="insertTmpEttAttr" parameterMap="EttAttrCall">
       { call INS_TMP_ETT_ATTR(?,?,?)}  
    </procedure>
```

oracle procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE INS_TMP_ETT_ATTR
(
  ettAttrLst IN CLOB,  
  pjtId IN VARCHAR2,
  createUser IN VARCHAR2
)
```

Everything works fine if the data length is not exceeded 3 million characters, but if more than that number, oracle will throw this exception: 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

I tried to search over internet but not much useful information. So any advice or idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the implementation of the ins_tmp_ett_attr procedure to your question. Does it contain any exception handling?

Comment: Which version of Oracle?  Which operating system?

Comment: Also, what character set encoding are you using?  Is it multi-byte?

Comment: no exception. handling in my procedure.
oracle 10g,win xp sp3.
multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit for CLOBs is 4 gig, so I guess you're dealing with a Varchar2 limitation which is exceeded in your PL/SQL code.

You'll have to look at the line numbers in the error stack. Usually Oracle provides additional ORA-06512 errors which indicate these PL/SQL objects and line numbers of the error stack.

Just a wild guess in case you're using multibyte characters: take care whether you specify the Varchar2 size in bytes (the default) or characters. The limit for varchar2 is 32767 bytes (not characters!)

**Edit after your comment below:**

review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716818/bulk-insert-from-java-into-oracle) for examples how to execute a batch insert

Comment: Tks, I wil lcheck.
By the way, I wonder if is there any configuration in Spring for oracle data source / transaction to deal with high load data?

Comment: none that i'm aware of. If your programm does 1 million insert statements without bind parameters there's no way to configure that to be a bulk load. Rule of thumb: 1000 rows w/o binds == 10.000 rows with binds == 1.000.000 rows bulk insert

Comment: I really don't get what you mean, can you explain in more detail?
In my prog, I concatenate inserted value into a clob param, and call procedure to insert it, in procedure, I split clob param into objects then insert, that's it.

Comment: Maybe you were right, my application use 2-bytes character (Korean character, it may make that error when the length of input string is bigger than length defined in DB.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this error when trying to write string in the blob,so i converted it to byte[] like this:

```
 byte[] bytes = content.getBytes();//conntent is a String contains more than 100 line date
```